# How to apply a function on selected dataframe columns and (depending on the outcome) return either the "initial value" or return 0?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm sorry if I'm being too vague, I'm an absolute beginner at R (and on StackOverflow).
To simplify (The bold part is my real "aim"):

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
##   Mass values  Sample 1   Sample 2  Sample x     Reference
## 1      50       6000       5866      36546        18000
## 2      51       8500      56547      346346       0
## 3      52       3600       7876      56856        96799
## 4      53       6324       5486      565676       68786
```

I want to apply the following function to all "SAMPLE" columns, not the mass values.
(I did this by creating a new data frame where I set Mass values as row names).

**

1. I want to apply a function of the following format: Sample value/Reference value = Ratio X
   IF ratio X > 2, I want to leave the "Sample value" as it's initial value in the data frame (and NOT replace it with the value resulting from the function/Ratio X). If Ratio X < 2 I want to return 0 and somehow remove all 0 values separately from the data frame at the end.
2. In case "Reference = 0" the function should not be applied to that specific row of sample values in the data frame.
   **
   I've tried using apply() and sapply(), this applied the function, but returned the solution as the new value in the dataframe columns. I was not able to find a way to just "check" the column values and return a value according to the functions'solution. I've tried an if else statement as well to do this, but this kept returning errors. I also tried:
   Ratio_X <- sample/reference
   dataframe[Ratio_x< 2] <- 0
   This also did not have the aimed result. I was wondering if anyone has a smart way to go about my problem to not replace my dataframe values when applying a function and not apply my function in case my reference value = 0 (for example in row 2 in my simplified dataframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dplyr` package makes this doable. Here is the first part (replacing with zero those values in the Sample columns where the Reference value is not zero but is more than half of the Sample value.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- structure(list(`Mass values` = c(50, 51, 52, 53), 
                       `Sample 1` = c(6000, 8500, 3600, 6324), 
                       `Sample 2` = c(5866, 56547, 7876, 5486), 
                       `Sample x` = c(36546, 346346, 56856, 565676), 
                       Reference = c(18000, 0, 96799, 68786)), 
                       row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                       class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

data1 <- data %>%
   # mutate changes values in columns
  mutate(across(starts_with("Sample"),  # across(starts_with()) only uses the Sample columns
                ~ case_when(Reference == 0 ~ .,   # if Reference == 0, return original value
                            # if value / Reference is > 2, return original value, else 0 
                            TRUE ~ if_else(. / Reference > 2, ., 0 )) ))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  `Mass values` `Sample 1` `Sample 2` `Sample x` Reference
          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1            50          0          0      36546     18000
2            51       8500      56547     346346         0
3            52          0          0          0     96799
4            53          0          0     565676     68786
```

Removing the zeros is a little trickier. Here are two ways.

```
# Replace with NA
data1 %>% na_if(0)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  `Mass values` `Sample 1` `Sample 2` `Sample x` Reference
          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>
1            50         NA         NA      36546     18000
2            51       8500      56547     346346        NA
3            52         NA         NA         NA     96799
4            53         NA         NA     565676     68786

# Pivot longer and remove rows with zero.
library(tidyr)
data1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Sample"), names_to = "Sample") %>%
  filter(value != 0)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  `Mass values` Reference Sample    value
          <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1            50     18000 Sample x  36546
2            51         0 Sample 1   8500
3            51         0 Sample 2  56547
4            51         0 Sample x 346346
5            53     68786 Sample x 565676
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I applied it to my dataframe and it appears to be working (still have to check the first part of the code with the ratio calculation. The entire dataframe is +20.000 cells, so finding values to check the function part with is a hassle but it looks like it worked!). You are really a lifesaver

Comment: Hi Ben, Somehow the "case_when and if_else" part of the code does not seem to work with me. I double checken and it is probably due to the fact you did something in the first step, you made a list out of the dataframe. May I ask why? Because the begin step is probably the one I do not fully understand.

Comment: @Amar, the first part of my post is the output of `dput()` on the data I used. A data.frame is a under the surface is just a list of class "data.frame". What is your `packageVersion("dplyr")`? Mine is 1.0.1.